# Using jQuery mCustomScrollbar and links to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm using jQuery mCustomScrollbar script to scroll the content element in one column with `id="scroll_box"`. I also have couple of images (in other column) who has anchor links to elements in `"scroll_box"`. The links has that syntax: `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=17#c33`.

I'm using that script for moving after click to anchor:

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
}
```

That piece of code working fine but only when I disable mCustomScrollbar script - so I don't have "good looking" and working scroller. When it's turned on the scroller looks and working ok, but anchor links didn't work...

My mCustomScrollbar code:

```
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#scroll_box").mCustomScrollbar({
                callbacks:{
                    onScroll:function(){
                        onScrollCallback();
                    },
                    onTotalScroll:function(){
                        onTotalScrollCallback();
                    },
                    onTotalScrollOffset:40,
                    onTotalScrollBack:function(){
                        onTotalScrollBackCallback();
                    },
                    onTotalScrollBackOffset:20
                }
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Is it possible to conect that two script into one working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the plugin have a lot of crazy issues! that make me drop it!; i just customize my self scroll bar and  delete this plugin from my project for same reason.

But i fixed the *scroll to anchor* by using **this solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a").click(function() {
if($(this).attr('href') == "#top"){
//this bit is for wordpress, where top is default: .entry-title
var elID=".entry-title";
$(".jsoverflow").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",elID);
}else{ 
if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf("#") >= 0){
//this bit is for any other anchor
$(".jsoverflow").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",$(this).attr('href'));

}

}

});
});
```

It's worked for me 100% and i get it from [Get-Hub](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/99).

Comment: I put this code in my main JS file , this code not correcting the origin code in same plugin file.